# jQuery Mobile submit with PHP without AJAX and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Sorry, I consider myself as a real newbie around jQuery Mobile. I'm not good at all regarding JavaScript. Here's the thing. I want to build a jQuery Mobile site without using AJAX. Just want the nice design from jQuery Mobile and then use PHP to submit forms etc.

I tried to build a simple page that submit first and last name to a MySQL database. It will submit, tell the user that it's submitted and then the user can press [Page 2] to see all the results. Now I use if(isset()) to display the message and else to display the form. So, the user who enter the site will get the form, when press [Submit] he/she will get the message that first and last name was submitted. Then press the button [Page 2] to see all the first and last names.

**PHP (index.php)**

```
if(isset($_POST['send'])) {

    $insert = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO name (fname, lname) VALUES(:fname, :lname)");
    $insert_array = array(
        ":fname" => $_POST['fname'],
        ":lname" => $_POST['lname']
    );

    $insert->execute($insert_array);

    $db = NULL;

    echo $_POST['fname'] . ' ' . $_POST['lname'] . ' was added!<br><br>';
}

else {
    echo '
    <form method="post" data-ajax="false">

        First name:
        <input type="text" name="fname"><br>

        Last name:
        <input type="text" name="lname"><br>

        <input type="submit" name="send" value="Add">

    </form><br>';
}

<a href="page2.php" data-role="button">Page 2</a>
```

**PHP (page2.php):**

```
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM name");

while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo $row['fname'] . ' ' . $row['lname'] . '<br>';
}

$db = NULL;

echo '<a href="index.php" data-role="button">Index</a>';
```

Let's say I enter "Test" as first and last name. It will echo out "Test Test was added!". If I now press [Page 2] I will see that "Test Test" was added. **BUT** when I then press [Index] to go back I want it to display the form again, but the message "Test Test was added!" is displayed again instead of the form, why? I have to update the page to get the form. Now, if I enable data-ajax it's working with submitting and back-button. **BUT** then I have to press update at page2.php when I get there to see all the first and last names. Do I make myself understood what's the problem?

Sorry, really new at jQuery Mobile and I can't find the answer at Google. Everyone is using JavaScript to submit data. Is it possible this way or do I have to learn JavaScript to submit forms? Read somewhere that using buttons instead of submit-buttons affect it.

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: This seems like a really odd thing to do. jQuery mobile is deeply intertwined with jQuery and AJAX functionality.  If you want the same look and feel, you could just copy the CSS portions of it and manually build your own HTML elements to use those classes, but even this would not give the same overall experience.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Ok, what do I need to do if I want the look and experience? Do I need to use JavaScript to serialize etc? Do I need a HTML-file, PHP-file and a JS-file to build ONE function? I like PHP because it's easy. I can have everything in one file. Yeah, I know I can have everything in one file with jQuery Mobile too but most people is talking about one HTML file is the best. Isn't it easier to divide the code into smaller pieces?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking to modify the DOM after the request? So post the form, add the user then display the results without having to click the button.

So on your ajax call use the done function to hide the form and show the results.

Take a look below and let me know if it helps.

EDIT: Added the .on click for the button. You may also want to look at adding a keypress checker to the inputs or an onsubmit on the form.

```
<div id="content">
<?php
if(isset($_POST['send'])) {

    $insert = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO name (fname, lname) VALUES(:fname, :lname)");
    $insert_array = array(
        ":fname" => $_POST['fname'],
        ":lname" => $_POST['lname']
    );

    $insert->execute($insert_array);

    $db = NULL;

    echo $_POST['fname'] . ' ' . $_POST['lname'] . ' was added!<br><br>';
}

else {
    echo '
    <form method="post" data-ajax="false" id="contentForm">

        First name:
        <input type="text" name="fname"><br>

        Last name:
        <input type="text" name="lname"><br>

        <input type="submit" name="send" value="Add" id="sendButton">

    </form><br>';
}
?>
</div>

<script type='text/javascript'>
<!-- https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ -->
$('#sendButton').on("click", function(){ 
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "page2.php",
      data: $('#contentForm').serialize()
    })
      .done(function( msg ) {
        $('#content').html( msg );
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Hmm, it doesn't work. :( What is DOM? Do I have to use serialize etc? Anyway, I tried it, with no luck. I can see the form flashes and then disappears. Can't I just use plain PHP with if(isset()) to check if the button is pressed? Why is the text still visible when I go back? It shouldn't because the message will just be visible if the button is pressed. I don't get it.

Comment: Sorry try again, I added an onpress to the button. It was just firing when the page loaded before.

Comment: Hmm, no doesn't work. Now the page works exactly like before. The message is still visible when I go back to index.php.

Comment: If you add unset($_POST['send']); after the insert will it may work unless there is something else posting send when using JQuery Mobile.

Comment: `unset($_POST['send']);` didn't worked. `$_POST = array();`? send, fname or ename. How do you want it?

Comment: $_POST = array(); should clear your post data. If after the insert you do this and there are still values coming into index.php I suspect you are posting to the page somehow when you click the index.php link. JQuery mobile may be taking over your anchors and adding onclick events to them. Hard to say without looking closer at the code.

Comment: Ok, that was a bit complicated. I just used `$_POST = array();` after the insert. Got undefined index at fname and lname when index.php tried to print the value at the screen. When you are building jQuery apps how do you do? Are you splitting every function up within one HTML-file, one PHP-file and one JS-file? Do you know any good, not complicated beginner guide? If it's the correct way to posting data?

Comment: You could also try to change the form from method="post" to method="get" with the code above. Because the AJAX call is post it should work but if JQuery mobile is taking over and submitting the form then it will be doing it (hopefully) with get and you will see the form. Just another suggestion to see what's happening.

Comment: Hmm, GET worked, with your code. I have ny idea why I need the JS, serialize etc but it worked. Thanks mate! :) But I don't like GET because it changes the link for me.

Comment: I made an app with HTML5/JQuery, most of them are entirely in JS and HTML (PHP/.NET/Java server side, but only works when online). Depends on what platforms you want to run on but PhoneGap is a nice way to get on multiple platforms with JQuery. I think they have a quick tutorial on how to get setup but will take a bit of programming knowledge.

Comment: Have tried PhoneGap. I created a very simple page to try out a lot of jQuery Mobile. packed it to a APK and installed it on my Android. Just static things. But the problem is when I tries to app PHP and SQL. So I need to create a seperate JS-file for every function. Like one for the login system, one for add users, one for ööh, you name it. Is that correct? The only thing I want is to post and fetch data. Yeah I have the really nice and smooth transactions within jQuery Mobile. :) So, need to learn JavaScript and post everything through JavaScript.

Comment: Yes, JavaScript is defiantly needed and that is the way to go about it. I make server pages (API) for all the calls to the server the app will need then return JSON/XML. I parse that with JavaScript and display it in the HTML. This is a good way to go about it, then in the future other people or apps can use the same server calls.

Comment: Aah, so the user just sees the HTML-file. Then you post it via JavaScript to the PHP-file and fetch data back? Do you know any good basic guide? Like Lynda or something? I think Lynda got one JavaScript guide, but not oriented to jQuery/jQuery Mobile.

Comment: Hi again, I got one question. Look at this tutorial: http://tutorialzine.com/2011/08/jquery-mobile-mvc-website-part-2/ He doesn't use JS at all. Just open and close the PHP-tag all the time. I am used to just open the PHP-tag once and echo out the HTML. Is his way (in the tutorial) one "correct" way if you don't want to use JS to submit/fetch data while using jQuery Mobile? He doesn't submit in the tutorial, just fetch, but it should work. My problem above was fetching data. What do you think? :)